# koa-views nunjucks: Error: template not found: master

Tags: node.js, koa, nunjucks

Structure:

```
|-server.js
|-views/
    |-master.njk
    |-index.njk
```

Koa-views configuration:

```
logit("Koa-views : subfolder used: /views");
var views = views('./views', { //note that I removed the __dirname to test if it was the cause
    extension: 'njk',
    map: {
        njk: 'nunjucks'
    },
    options: {
        helpers: {
            uppercase: (str) => str.toUpperCase(),
            lowercase: (str) => str.toLowerCase(),
        },

    }
});
koa.use(views);
```

index.njk

```
{% extends "master" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Pretty lame content...</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

master.njk

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        "Master page here" => {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Log output:

```
NodeJS server started, it is running on port 3000

  Template render error: (unknown path)
    Error: template not found: master
      at Object.exports.prettifyError (/srv/NodesProjects/AnotherNodeTry/node_modules/nunjucks/src/lib.js:34:15)
      at /srv/NodesProjects/AnotherNodeTry/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:489:31
      at eval (eval at _compile (/srv/NodesProjects/AnotherNodeTry/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:568:24), <anonymous>:9:11)
      at createTemplate (/srv/NodesProjects/AnotherNodeTry/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:213:25)
      at next (/srv/NodesProjects/AnotherNodeTry/node_modules/nunjucks/src/lib.js:210:13)
      at handle (/srv/NodesProjects/AnotherNodeTry/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:253:25)
      at /srv/NodesProjects/AnotherNodeTry/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:264:21
      at next (/srv/NodesProjects/AnotherNodeTry/node_modules/nunjucks/src/lib.js:207:13)
      at Object.exports.asyncIter (/srv/NodesProjects/AnotherNodeTry/node_modules/nunjucks/src/lib.js:214:5)
      at new_cls.getTemplate (/srv/NodesProjects/AnotherNodeTry/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:243:17)
      at new_cls.root [as rootRenderFunc] (eval at _compile (/srv/NodesProjects/AnotherNodeTry/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:568:24), <anonymous>:8:5)
      at new_cls.render (/srv/NodesProjects/AnotherNodeTry/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:482:15)
      at new_cls.renderString (/srv/NodesProjects/AnotherNodeTry/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:328:21)
      at Object.module.exports.renderString (/srv/NodesProjects/AnotherNodeTry/node_modules/nunjucks/index.js:80:14)
      at /srv/NodesProjects/AnotherNodeTry/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:1174:11
      at /srv/NodesProjects/AnotherNodeTry/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:144:5
```

I verify that every file have chmod 777 and same user.
If I replace with only 1 variable and try to pass it with the render function it works. But includes and extends seems off.

I tried on another project with another backend and it's working - but I'm not good enough to go through all the source code and figure it out :(

I wish the traceback was more detailed, no complete path :(

**Edit**
I forgot, this is how I call the templace

```
router.get('/', async function (ctx, next) {
    await ctx.render('index', {test: 'Hello'})
})
```

**Edit 2**
I tried using koaNunjucks2 lib, it works when I put the .njk at the end of my extends, must be related to the package koa-views.

Comment: `var views = views('./views'` is a very strange code. Are you really want override `views` function?

Comment: The `views` function is provided with the package. See [koa-views doc](https://github.com/queckezz/koa-views). I opened an issue with them on GitHub too.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const views = require('koa-views');
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
const nunjucksEnvironment = new nunjucks.Environment(
    new nunjucks.FileSystemLoader(path.join(__dirname, './views'))
);

const koa = new Koa();

koa.use(views(path.join(__dirname, './views'), {
    extension: 'njk',
    options: {
        nunjucksEnv: nunjucksEnvironment
    },
    map: { njk: 'nunjucks' }
}));
```

Reference: https://github.com/queckezz/koa-views/blob/6994e23e0f02a83d30b3ab9bea56ae79b37a07fa/test/index.js#L252

Comment: Same issue as the question, and this exactly solved it.

Comment: And I just found, pass the relative path of the view folder to the CWD to the first parameter of both `FileSystemLoader` and `koa-views` works too.

Answer (score 1):

```
const path = require('path');
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();
const router = require('./routes/index');
const views = require('koa-views');
app.use(
  views(path.join(__dirname, 'views'), {
    extension: 'njk',
    map: { njk: 'nunjucks' },
    options: { settings: { views: path.join(__dirname, 'views') } }
  })
);
```

Reference: https://github.com/queckezz/koa-views/issues/92